# Issue in plotting a stacked bar graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a stacked bar chart but I am unable to retrieve the expected output

```
m1_t = pd.DataFrame({
'cat1': [13.22,43.20,146.38],
'cat2':[609.52,663.49,591.76,577.89],
'cat3':[230,5010,5010,1250],
'output_data':[12.545,12.545,3.137,2.123]
})

m1_t[['cat1','cat2','cat3']].plot(kind='bar', width = width)
m1_t['output_data'].plot(secondary_y=True)
ax = plt.gca()
plt.xlim([-width, len(m1_t['cat3'])-width])
ax.set_xticklabels(("1", "2", "3", "4"))
```

plt.show()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `stacked=True` to `plot` to get stacked bar chart:

```
m1_t[['cat1','cat2','cat3']].plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
m1_t['output_data'].plot(secondary_y=True)
```

Output:

[image]